# Deriving FROM existing Dockerfile + setting USER to non-root

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, openshift

I'm trying to find a generic best practice for how to:

1. Take an arbitrary (parent) Dockerfile, e.g. one of the official Docker images that run their containerized service as root,
2. Derive a custom (child) Dockerfile from it (via `FROM ...`),
3. Adjust the *child* in the way that it runs the same service as the *parent*, but as non-root user.

I've been searching and trying for days now but haven't been able to come up with a satisfying solution.

I'd like to come up with an approach e.g. similar to the following, simply for adjusting the user the original service runs as:

```
FROM mariadb:10.3

RUN chgrp -R 0 /var/lib/mysql && \
    chmod g=u /var/lib/mysql

USER 1234
```

However, the issue I'm running into again and again is whenever the *parent* Dockerfile declares some path as `VOLUME` (in the example above actually `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql`), that effectively makes it impossible for the *child* Dockerfile to adjust file permissions for that specific path. The `chgrp` & `chmod` are without effect in that case, so the resulting docker container won't be able to start successfully, due to file access permission issues.

I understand [that the `VOLUME` directive works that way by design](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) and also [why it's like that](http://container42.com/2014/11/03/docker-indepth-volumes/), but to me it seems that it completely prevents a simple solution for the given problem: Taking a Dockerfile and adjusting it in a simple, clean and minimalistic way to run as non-root instead of root.

The background is: I'm trying to run arbitrary Docker images on an Openshift Cluster. [Openshift by default prevents running containers as root](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#use-uid), which I'd like to keep that way, as it seems quite sane and a step into the right direction, security-wise.

This implies that a solution like `gosu`, expecting the container to be started as root in order to drop privileges during runtime isn't good enough here. I'd like to have an approach that doesn't require the container to be started as root at all, but only as the specified `USER` or even with a random UID.

The unsatisfying approaches that I've found until now are:

- Copy the *parent* Dockerfile and adjust it in the way necessary (effectively duplicating code)
- `sed`/`awk` through all the service's config files during build time to replace the original `VOLUME` path with an alternate path, so the `chgrp` and `chmod` can work (leaving the original `VOLUME` path orphaned).

I really don't like these approaches, as they require to really dig into the logic and infrastructure of the *parent* Dockerfile and how the service itself operates.

So there must be better ways to do this, right? What is it that I'm missing? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the case of MariaDB, have you looked at the MariaDB image that OpenShift often ships included. It is already set up to run as non root per OpenShift requirements so can be used with no special work required.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, thank you. MariaDB is just an example. I'm trying to find a generic approach for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions on volume mount points don't matter at all, the mount covers up whatever underlying permissions were there to start with. Additionally you can set this kind of thing at the Kubernetes level rather than worrying about the Dockerfile at all. This is usually though a PodSecurityPolicy but you can also set it in the SecurityContext on the pod itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/ regarding the Kubernetes concept of PodSecurityPolicy, but it's not obvious to me which Control Aspects you have in mind when saying "you can set this kind of thing via PodSecurityPolicy". Are you talking about the permissions on file system level? Or about extending some kind of capabilities/privileges in order to work around the permission problem?

Comment: Btw, I'd actually even prefer a solution that doesn't require me to derive a child Dockerfile from the original one, i.e. solving this in the Kubernetes or Openshift layer.

Comment: In this case you probably care mostly about runAsUser, runAsGroup, and fsGroup. The first two override the user/group info in the container metadata and set a specific UID and GID to run the processes as. The third will set the permissions on the volume to match.

Comment: But should be noted that to do that requires you being cluster admin, which for OpenShift with its multi tenant model, normal developers aren't going to have. That said, in the context of OpenShift, what you need to do is explained in https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it led me into the right direction for solving my problems. I'm now using Kubernetes/Openshift means for avoiding the "root vs. non-root" pitfalls that the original Dockerfiles pose.

Specifically, _fsGroup_, _runAsGroup_ and _runAsUser_ provide a generic way for how to circumvent the (file system permission related) issues created by a Dockerfile that originally expects to run as root user.